# How use JQuery with Sencha touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, sencha-touch

How use JQuery and Sencha Touch. For example I have a sencha button, on click nothing happens. JQuery work I check.

```javascript
xtype: 'button',
text: 'Get result',
docked: 'bottom',
id: 'myBtn',
```

and have JQuery

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {  
//alert('true');
    $("#myBtn").click(function() {
        alert('true');
        console.log('info');
    });
});
```

It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be mixing these two frameworks they dont play nice with each other. I believe that sencha uses the id property for its own internal query. Hence using jQuery to get elements on its own its not possible. But if you want to truly use the above code try the following
    $(Ext.query('#myBtn')[0]).whatever_you_want_to_chain